# setcookie not working - store invalid value

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

I have a complete code in which i setcookie and on form submit i match it with posted data but its not valid but when i use a echo command just after setcookie its working please check the code below . when you un-comment the echo command just after the setcookie its working try it yourself and please give me its solution . I m using xampp and i try it on two diff-diff xampp

```
 <?php
    $msg='';
    if(isset($_POST['reset_password'])){
      if (isset($_POST["CSRFtoken"], $_COOKIE["CSRFtoken"])){
          if ($_POST["CSRFtoken"] == $_COOKIE["CSRFtoken"]){
            $msg = 'yes';
          }else{
            $msg ='invalid request';
          }
        }
      }
    $token = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
    setcookie("CSRFtoken", $token, time() + 60 * 60 * 24);
//echo 's';
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href=" ">
    <title>Fitness - Free Bootstrap 4 Template</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php if($msg!=""){echo $msg;} ?>
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="user" id="user"  class="form-control" placeholder="Email/Mobile"/>                   
          <input name="CSRFtoken" id="CSRFtoken" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="reset_password" value="Reset" class="btn btn-primary">

        </div>
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: debugging: `var_dump($_COOKIE);` as the first line of the script. It will show you if the cookie is being returned from the cient.

Comment: When i use var_dump($_COOKIE); its start working as i use echo means when we print anything before <html> tag it start working otherwise its give wrong value. @RyanVincent Please try this complete code in your PC

Comment: Working sample code at: [Pastebin.com : questions/46999010/setcookie-not-working-store-invalid-value](https://pastebin.com/rKLPxQRG). It is commented. Post a comment if any issues.

Comment: Dear @RyanVincent you use session but i want it in cookie

Comment: Cookie version - Working sample code: [questions/46999010/setcookie-not-working - cookie version](https://pastebin.com/YasvRPnX). :)